# A poem, for you

Tags: cipher, steganography

Mahapps I am lost, perhaps that's a given,

Like I was never there, gone with a whizz,

Given the time, you will forget our puzzling,

So leave me now, go back to your browsing!

Remember me from then, when I still knew luv,

More then the shell I am now, as prickly as cacti

Then alone I shall be, so leave me, I beseech.

> Because, in the end, ___________

HINT #1

> Finally into remembering steganography tag?

HINT #2

> Although the blooming answer's sure hidden

<sup>I honestly thought this would get solved quite quickly...I'm surprised</sup>

Comment: Has it got anything to do with spelling errors?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire it wouldn't be steganography if they told you where the information is hidden :)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire It, uh, has something to do with the poem.... _nailed it, best hint ever_

Comment: Hmm.. "Mahapps" could means "Whatsapp" as the hint showed "Interestedin" for "Linkedin". Don't know, maybe the typos are related to some tech company name (?)

Comment: Or the hint is telling us that the poem has wrong punctuation or words with the wrong ending...

Comment: @athin good idea, but wrong direction, sorry. No tech companys involved

Comment: Well - First, I think the hint has helped quite a bit with the steganography part..  Still struggling with the cipher part unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because, in the end, ...

> ... **nothing matters**.

The answer ...

> ... is hidden in the first and last letters of each line, which spell *Mlgsrmt Nzggvih*.
>
>  This text can be converted to the answer above with [Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash), a monoalphabetic substitution cipher which replaces A with Z, B with Y, C with X and so on.
>
>  The strange last letters of some of the line endings (luv, whizz, cacti) stand out and acrostics are always a possibility, but I can't see any hints hidden in the poem. (But perhaps "in the end" is a hint to take the line endings?) Acrostics are hard to spot when the letters are encoded.
>
>  I now see that the additional hints are acrostics of "first" and "atbash". I didn't see them when solving the puzzle; I just tried out some simple ciphers on the first and last letters on a hunch.

Comment: Correct! Yup, "In the end" was supposed to help point at the last letters, since they could be trickier to find.